# Android Studio not saving settings

Tags: android-studio

When I make a change in Android Studio settings to Editor > File and Code Templates the changes are reset if I close and restart Android Studio. I've tried this for both the "Default" and "Project" profiles. Is there something I'm missing or is this a bug?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio 3.0 - Settings are not saved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49295679/android-studio-3-0-settings-are-not-saved)

Comment: Any solution? This is frustrating me beyond belief.