# Android Studio 3.0 - Settings are not saved

Tags: android, android-studio, settings

I've increased the "Right margin (columns)" in File->Settings->Editor->Code Style from default 100 to 140. Unfortunately the margin is reset after each time I restart Android Studio. I also tried to export and import my settings but this does not prevent the right margin to be reset.

Hopefully someone can tell me how to save the margin.

Comment: Which OS are you on?

Comment: In the Scheme, have you tried to setup as property of the project, and not Default property of the IDE?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are selecting the **default** option in Code Style then it is going to reset again to `100` value

Try to select **Project** from Scheme and apply the setting it is working

if You are setting it **default** then it is reset to it default value

[image: File->Settings->Editor->Code Style]

Comment: What is the point of being able to edit the Default scheme if it is just going to reset itself when a new project is created? I can't wrap my head around this. When you select `File>Other Settings>Settings for New Projects...` you can edit the Default scheme, but the settings aren't applied to new projects and you end up having to customize everything over and over again. It's ridiculous.

Comment: **Why Default Setting?** It is because if the user doesn't set any settings and doesn't know why it has been used, most of the people does not aware of it. It has given special provision to change according to the project so that's why it is project based setting as per my knowledge.

Comment: Not works for me, I have to change the code style each time when I close and open Android studio again....

Answer (score 3):

Just remove the next row from `gradle.properties`

```
kotlin.code.style=official
```

Dont forget to re-apply codestyle settings in IDE settings or in `/.idea/codeStyles/`